# React Native: UI is not proper in Android, but working fine in iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to ReactNative. I have implemented a UI in React Native, where it is working fine in **iOS** But in case of **Android**, it is showing some white space over the button. Please check the below screenshots.

[image: Android Screenshot]     [image: iOS Screenshot]

Here is my code that I am using:

```
export default  class SignUpPage extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Sign Up',
  };
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.fbButtonContainer}>
          <Button onPress={this._onPress} title="SIGN UP WITH FACEBOOK" color="#FFFFFF" accessibilityLabel="Tap on Me"/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textEmailInputContainer} >
          <Image source={require('./Images/mail_icon.png')} style={styles.imageIcons}/>
          <TextInput placeholder="Your Email Address" style={styles.txtInput}/>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.textPasswordInputContainer}>
          <Image source={require('./Images/password_icon.png')} style={styles.imageIcons}/>
          <TextInput placeholder="Create Password" style={styles.txtInput}/>
        </View>

          <View style={styles.magentaButtonContainer}>
            <Button 
              onPress={() => navigate('SignIn', {name: 'Jane'})}
              title="SIGN UP" color="#FFFFFF" accessibilityLabel="Tap on Me"/>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And Style is below:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageIcons: {
    left: 11,
    top: 12,
  },
  fbButtonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#3855ca',
    borderRadius: 24,
    padding: 2,
    marginLeft: 18,
    marginRight: 18,
    top: 35,
    height: 47,
  },
  magentaButtonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#ca375e',
    borderRadius: 24,
    padding: 2,
    marginLeft: 18,
    marginRight: 18,
    bottom: 55,
    top: 5,
    height: 47,
  },
  textEmailInputContainer: {
    flexDirection:'row',
    backgroundColor: '#efefef',
    borderRadius: 4,
    padding: 2,
    marginLeft: 18,
    marginRight: 18,
    marginTop: 80,
    height: 48,
  },
  textPasswordInputContainer: {
    flexDirection:'row',
    backgroundColor: '#efefef',
    borderRadius: 4,
    padding: 2,
    marginLeft: 18,
    marginRight: 18,
    marginTop: 10,
    height: 48,
  },
  txtInput: {
    top: 0,
    height: 36,
    marginLeft: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

***Please help me out to fix this.***

**There is one more problem the Sign Up button I want to set to bottom with space of 55px. But couldn't achieve it, the way we do in iOS by setting bottom constraint. Please let me know any solution for this as well.**

Comment: I can't see any screenshot ?

Comment: Please check now..

Comment: first i should say its just a guess, cause i don't have the full info. i think u r using pre-made UI components from somewhere. the white box showing over ur button in android is nothing but that button.i guess the button in ur using package is handled to be rendered in white BG in android but transparent in IOS. so u see IOS is ok but in android its not. i recommend u to create ur own UI components cause u have more control over them(u will need button a lot of times in future, so make one for urself). i hope it helped

Comment: Yes, Amas. I created by own UI using Touchable Opacity. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style of Button UI component is different in android and ios. You can create a custom button using touchable opacity and apply styles as you need.

### Example

```
<View>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitContainer} >
     <Text style={styles.submitText}>POST DISH</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

**Css style**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   submitContainer:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        backgroundColor:'#f7aa97',
        width:'100%',
        height:40,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I did now. Can you also help me in setting this SIGN UP button at the bottom with gap of 50 pixels from bottom. I tried all the way, but didn't get any result.

Comment: Hope this will help you. the resolutions for devices are different so we need to get the screen height and width and then we can give height or margin bottom based the screen height .
Example
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);  
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);
 <View style={styles.mapView}>
            <Text>something</Text>
</View>
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
mapView:{
    width:SCREEN_WIDTH,
    height:SCREEN_HEIGHT - 300,
  }
})

Comment: @GeethaTulasiBalam I have posted a similar question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875092/why-is-this-react-native-screen-different-on-android-and-ios?noredirect=1#comment109455426_61875092, if you can, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `overflow: 'hidden'` to your button style :
For ex:

```js
fbButtonContainer: {
    ...// your styles,
    overflow: 'hidden'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Platform react native component and style separately for android device.
For eaxmple:

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
```

This is my input box design and i need to use different height for iOS and android so i used below code:

This is my text field cod

```
<TextInput
                    keyboardType='email-address'
                    style = {styles.inputBox}
                    placeholder="Email Address"
                    placeholderTextColor="#333"
                    onChangeText = {fbEmail => this.setState({fbEmail})}
                  />
```

This is style for textfield.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputBox:{
        width:width*0.65 ,
        borderBottomColor: 'grey',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        height:Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 24 : height/15,
        fontSize:16,
        color:'#333',
        marginVertical:10,
        paddingLeft: 5
      }
});
```