# React Native Paper: Margins don't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-paper

I am currently working with Expo, using React Native Paper for TextInputs, Switches, etc.

Everything works well in the Web-View, but when I try it on my iPhone, the margins on the React-Native-Paper components dont work. All the objects are directly touching each other, despite having large margins.

Icons also don't display on iOS.

I also made a custom RadioButton component that uses fading images instead of circles and it is also buggy on the iPhone, despite working on PC.

Do you have an idea how to solve this issue?

I am looking forward to your advice!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is a common behavior for react native, DYOR.
[Most relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875092/react-native-app-with-same-code-but-different-result-for-vertical-margins-in-ios)